# ajax post with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

why isn't this working?

**jQuery AJAX Code:**

```
$("header input").bind("keyup", function()
{
    var searchString= $("header input").val();
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false
    });
});
```

**PHP Code(Just a test Code):**

```
if($_POST["search"]) {
    echo "TEST MESSAGE!";
}
```

It doesn't show The echo :/

thanks for ur help ;)

Comment: Is an `echo` statement shown before the if statement? Can you post the whole php method?

Comment: yes there are a few echo methods before that

Comment: You don't have a callback? so it doesn't show. it only posts the message and thats it

Comment: just call 
success:function(data)
{
       alert(data);
}

Comment: It doesn't echo anywhere. You will get only response from the server.

Comment: [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791638/passing-javascript-string-into-php-string/23791777#23791777) its a dulicate.

Comment: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140620/nkazv44j.png  http://s7.directupload.net/images/140620/485fykpk.png   Thats my problem... it shows me the page twice if i enter a word to search :O

Answer (score 1):

You need to display the data you receive from the ajax call. 
Example, to put the result into a `<div>` called `YourresultDiv`:

Try with this

```
$("header input").on("keyup", function () {
    var searchString = $("header input").val();
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#YourresultDiv').html(data);
            alert("Successful");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks that worked... I just forgot the succes method and i appended a div      

    <div id="resultDiv"></div>
    //and thats the succes method i forgot
    success: function (data) {
    $('#resultDiv').html(data);
    }

but now if i write something in my input field, it shows me the whole page again?! ^^
if you want i can upload a screenshot?

thx for the fast answers :)

Comment: Here are the screens:
s14.directupload.net/images/140620/nkazv44j.png s7.directupload.net/images/140620/485fykpk.png

Answer (score 1):

Hopes this will help you....

```
$("header input").bind("keyup", function()
{
    var searchString= $("header input").val();
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        async: false
    },success: function (data) {


     $('div#posteddata').append(data);

    }

);
});


<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="posteddata"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an element you want to update.. for example

```
<div id="result"> </div>
```

and then append a success event handler to your ajax call

```
        $("header input").bind("keyup", function () {
            var searchString = $("header input").val();
            var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
            alert(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false
            }).success(function (data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("Ajax failed!");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

In js add

```
success: function (data) {
        // success handler
    }
```

as your response handler

```
if($_POST["data"]) {
  // search = search string available here  in $_POST['data']
  echo "TEST MESSAGE!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your call back function in $.ajax() function,with callback function only,you can display anything through an ajax request..

So try this.

```
$("header input").on("keyup", function () {
    var searchString = $("header input").val();
    var dataString = 'search=' + searchString;
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Yourdiv').html(data);  // or $('#Yourdiv')text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Without success function,you can see the echoed statement in your network segment in console.

for that, press `F12`,then you will get a link like 
XHR finished loading: POST `"http://localhost/yourproject/func_name`.Click on that link and you will goto `network` segment and from there,click on the function name and then in `response` or `preview` tab,you canb see the echoed statement..
try it.